# Error Message "Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object" with Blazor Two-Way Binding Search Bar - Am I Handling the Model Incorrectly?

Tags: c#, .net, razor, binding, blazor

I wrote this following code that works great when passing strings

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="@searchTerm" Placeholder="Sök" />

@foreach (var item in filteredItems)
{
    <p>@item</p>
}

@code {
    private string searchTerm = "";
    private List<string> items = new List<string> {
        "1","2","3"
    };

    private IEnumerable<string> filteredItems =>
        items.Where(i => i.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()));
}
```

I then changed the code but passed in a Model Exercise but that dosent work

I give me on the console the following error.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> at

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="@searchTerm" Placeholder="Sök" />

@foreach (var item in filteredItems)
{
    <p>@item.Title</p>
}

@code {
    private string searchTerm = "";
    private List<Exercise> items = new List<Exercise> {
        new Exercise
        {
            Id = 1,
            Title = "Push-ups",
            Instructions = new Dictionary<int, string>()
            {
                { 1, "Get into a plank position with your hands slightly wider than shoulder-width apart." },
                { 2, "Lower your body until your chest nearly touches the floor." },
                { 3, "Push your body back up to the starting position, keeping your elbows close to your body." }
            }
        },
        new Exercise
        {
            Id = 2,
            Title = "Squats",
            Instructions = new Dictionary<int, string>()
            {
                { 1, "Stand with your feet shoulder-width apart." },
                { 2, "Lower your body as if you are sitting back into a chair." },
                { 3, "Keep your knees over your ankles and your weight in your heels." },
                { 4, "Push back up to the starting position." }
            }
        },
        new Exercise
        {
            Id = 3,
        }
    };

    private IEnumerable<Exercise> filteredItems =>
        items.Where(i => i.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()));
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas why? At first i tired to use my IExerciseDataStore to fetch my exercises but I keep getting the same problem over and over.

```
@inject IExerciseDataStore<Exercise> exerciseDataStore
...

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();

    items = await exerciseDataStore.GetAllExercisesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Excercise 3 does not have a title, so it throws when you try to access it in the @foreach loop. You need to set `Title` as nullable in your `Excercise` class if not all instances have a title.

Comment: Add the `?` in `<p>@item?.Title</p>`

Comment: Also have you considered using the `Autocomplete` component in MudBlazor?

Answer (score 0):

The Binding was correctly formulated when using MudBlazor, doc to read [more](https://mudblazor.com/docs/overview).
In summary: @bind-Value="SearchTerm" will also bind ValueChanged="SearchTerm" in the "background".

The problem I had was what @Axekan wrote in the comments i keep getting NullReferenceExccption because the data I had was null when loading the page.

```
         ...
            new Exercise
            {
               Id = 3,
            }
```

Properties as Title or Instruction was not set and will be null since Title - string, Instructions - Dictionary these are references types, if not set will point to null on Model (Exercise) initalization.

Instead change to this: To solve the Null Reference i had loading the page.

```
         ...
            new Exercise
            {
               Id = 3,
               Title = String.Empty,
               Instructions = new Dictornary<int,string>()
            }
```

Since the Exeption came from searching on Title and title was null. This problem would be solved by just adding String.Empty or "".

```
private IEnumerable<Exercise> filteredItems =>
        items.Where(i => i.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()));
```